# Is it possible to load my graphic on picturebox2, then load in picturebox1?

Tags: vb6

my graphic is like below :

```
Private Sub pin8_Paint()
pin8.Line (48, 48)-(168, 96), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (56, 48)-(72, 32), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (82, 48)-(98, 32), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (108, 48)-(124, 32), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (134, 48)-(150, 32), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (56, 96)-(72, 112), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (82, 96)-(98, 112), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (108, 96)-(124, 112), vbBlack, B
pin8.Line (134, 96)-(150, 112), vbBlack, B
End Sub
```

Then I would like to load into pic1 by commandbutton. Any idea?

Regards,
Chan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235120%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), which does exactly what you are looking for, I modified your code with a couple of changes:

```
Private Sub pin8_Paint()
  pin8.AutoRedraw = True
  pin8.Line (48, 48)-(168, 96), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (56, 48)-(72, 32), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (82, 48)-(98, 32), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (108, 48)-(124, 32), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (134, 48)-(150, 32), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (56, 96)-(72, 112), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (82, 96)-(98, 112), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (108, 96)-(124, 112), vbBlack, B
  pin8.Line (134, 96)-(150, 112), vbBlack, B
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  pin8Clone.Picture = pin8.Image
End Sub
```

The key here is the 1st line of the Paint() event, where `AutoRedraw` is set to True.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245029%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) says that setting this to True, tells the PictureBox control to write the graphic to an in-memory Image object instead of just to the UI.  This allows you to later grab the graphic via the `Image` property.

Comment: izit i cnt use the .paintpicture??
for example:
Private Sub ShowPictureAtPosition(pX As Single, pY As Single)
    With mainbox
        
        .Cls
       .PaintPicture mPic, pX + 1, pY + 1, mPicWidth, mPicHeight
       
        
    End With
End Sub